# CallWindowProc() generates error 5 (Access is denied)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, error-handling

I'm trying to resolve error, that I get with `GetLastError()` during execution of `CallWindowProc`. The code is as follows:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK editSubProc(HWND h, UINT m, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
//some implementation
//GetLastError() returns 0 here
CallWindowProc(edit_proc,h,m,w,l);
}
```

Creation of window looks like below:

```
HWND ch=CreateWindowEx(style,"Edit","",dwstyle,l,t,r-l,b-t,hwnd,0,hInst,0);
edit_proc=(WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(ch,GWLP_WNDPROC);
SetWindowLongPtr(ch,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)editSubProc);
```

Now, the scenario is, that main loop calls `IsDialogMessage(...)`, which invokes `editSubProc`, which,through `CallWindowProc`, again invokes `editSubProc`. On the beggining of second invokation of `editSubProc`, `GetLastError` returns 5.
Everything is invoked from the same thread. What could be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: this api not set last error and no sense call `GetLastError` here

Comment: That means some function got "access denied". Which function? Who cares? It could be any function in the entire program or the Windows OS. It's pretty useless information.

Comment: Correct me please if I'm wrong, but since before executing `CallWindowProc` error was 0 and after/during its execution error is 5, it means that something set it.

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't look like it will compile. What value does your `editSubProc` return? If it returns the wrong value, it may be called recursively, forever. Maybe try `return CallWindowProc(edit_proc,h,m,w,l);` instead?

Comment: The result of `GetLastError()` is only meaningful immediately after calling a function that is documented to set it, and then (usually) only when that function reports a generic error through some other means, such as a return value. In all other cases, you can't tell anything from it.

Comment: Move `GetLastError()` up "line by line", You can even put it after every code line, if you wish. The main target is to find "exact call", "exact line" which generates effective error.

Comment: @arn You don't need to change code to get the last error code in a debugger. Just add a `@err,hr` watch and you're all set. Of course you need to know, when that watch holds meaningful data.

Comment: Does this error have any subsequent effects on your application? If not, please try to ignore this error code. There is no description in [`CallWindowProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-callwindowproca#return-value) that you can use `GetLastError` to retrieve the error code. In addition, the error code may also occur in `edit_proc`

Answer (score 0):

`GetLastError()` returns the last error that happened (it even says so in the name!).

So the last error that happened was "access denied".

When did it happen? No clue. Was it supposed to happen? No idea. Is it a problem? Probably not. There are lots of reasons why access might be denied to *something*, and perhaps some part of the Windows OS just wanted to see *whether* it had access to something.

You should call `GetLastError` *when you get an error and the documentation tells you to call it to get the error code*. Otherwise you just get whatever the last error that happened was, which might be a completely different part of the program, maybe where there was *supposed* to be an error. You're making up imaginary problems, where none exist.